# Start threads after queue with task that calls functions in another module, Python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, queue, tk-toolkit

I want to call functions in a tkinter application from a threading class in another module. The queue self.tasks get a function call added in t and after t runs the threads thread1 and thread2 are to follow and lastly a second queue item in t3 should follow alike t. The queue tasks t and t3 are function calls for two functions in a Tkinter application in the second module,M1. At the moment only queue task t runs so I wonder how to get thread1 and thread2 and t3 to be run after t?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import Queue

import Tkinter as tk
import threading



class Parser(threading.Thread):
    """Thread executing tasks from a given tasks queue"""
    def __init__(self,tasks,num_threads):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.tasks = Queue.Queue()
        self.daemon = True
        self.work_begin = Queue.Queue()
        self.work_queue = Queue.PriorityQueue()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            func, args, kwargs = self.tasks.get()
            try:
                func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception,e:
                print e
            finally:
                self.tasks.task_done()


    def add_task(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        """Add a task to the queue"""
        self.tasks.put((func, args, kwargs))

    def repeat_task(self,n, function, *args, **kwargs):
        for i in range(n): function(*args, **kwargs)
        return ''


    def wait_completion(self):
        """Wait for completion of all the tasks in the queue"""
        self.tasks.join()

    def some_function():
        return "some code"

    def another_function():
        return "some_code"


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Parser(10,20)

    # add to queue self.tasks

    t = pool.add_task(tkinter_function())

    t.get()

    # threads thread1 and thread2 should start after the tkinter function in
    # the queue self.tasks, t

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=pool.some_function, args=())
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=pool.another_function, args=())


    thread1 = Thread(1,t1,1)

    thread2 = Thread(2,t2,2)

    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
```

Comment: Do you know `Thread.join()`?

Comment: it's in the function wait_completion(self) in the class Parser() but I'm not sure how to use it, if I should pass the threads to the function for instance, with multiple and combined queues and threads so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Another advice for getting answers: if your question is about the threads, throw all code away that distracts, that does not help understanding the problem. Begin with line 1. Otherwise fewer people will read it because they get distracted. I will wait until you edited the sourceode. If you have 20 lines left that would be very good.